# Gradle Shadow Duplicate File Names in Jar

Tags: java, gradle, ant, gradle-shadow-plugin

I'm trying to migrate from an Ant build to a Gradle build.  I am using Shadow (`com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0`) to build my project. My project includes 3 Apache Axiom dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-api', version: '1.2.13'
implementation group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-dom', version: '1.2.13'
implementation group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-impl', version: '1.2.13'
```

The Shadow configuration looks like this:

```
shadowJar {
    baseName = project.name
    classifier = ''
    archiveVersion = ''
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
}
```

When these jars are built with my Ant project, I end up with 2 `axiom.xml` files in `META-INF` in the jar. Both are different.

[image: Ant axiom.xml]

When I build with Shadow I end up with the latter of the two `axiom.xml` files.  The first file is being overwritten by the latter.

[image: Gradle axiom.xml]

This causes a runtime error. How can I get Shadow to include files of duplicate files names instead of just overwriting them?

Comment: Would [merging the files](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/#appending-xml-files) do the trick?

Comment: In this case no

Comment: I take that back.  I didn't see that there was an XML specific method.  I tried just `append` before and that didn't work.  Using the `XmlAppendingTransformer` on it did the trick.  Still would be nice if you could just include duplicates though.

Comment: I used `com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer` to append `reference.conf` files. It does merge the `reference.conf` file by creates a bunch of duplicates for other files like `applicatin.conf`. Any Idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Okay found the issue. adding `with jar` at the end made it bundle the same thing twice.